# SWRevealView Library, main view should not be accessible after side bar is opened

Tags: ios, slider, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController library for making side bar menu in IOS from the link http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

The problem is that when the sidebar menu is opened I don't want the user to access the main view ( it is the viewController in which I have the navigation button and the pan gesture for getting the slider out are present ) so that when side bar is opened and user is touching right of the screen on the main view any button or any tableView  on the main view should not be accessible. Can anyone tell me how to do this in this library

Comment: u want to access the main VC only in button action,if u reply in quickly it is easy to solve ur problem

Comment: I did not understood what you said but I do not want the main View Controller to respond to any click(e.g trigger any segue) when slide bar menu is opened